# Remove certain fields from a line

Tags: command-line, scripts, text-processing, rsync, cut-command

I have the following lines in a file:

```
Modified folders: html/project1/old/dev/vendor/symfony/yaml/Tests/bla.yml
Modified folders: html/port5/.DS_Store
Modified folders: html/trap/dev8/.DS_Store
Modified folders: html/bla3/test/appl/.DS_Store
Modified folders: html/bla4/pro1/app/bla/Api2.php
Modified folders: html/bla10/dev/appl/language/.DS_Store
Modified folders: html/bla11/dev/appl/language/abc.txt
```

This is basically output of `rsync`. I would like to list all the lines of the file up to 3 directory places, like

```
Modified folders: html/project1/old
Modified folders: html/port5
Modified folders: html/trap/dev8
Modified folders: html/bla3/test
Modified folders: html/bla4/pro1
Modified folders: html/bla10/dev
Modified folders: html/bla11/dev
```

Can anyone please provide me any command or shell script to do the same?

Comment: your post has been destroyed by markdown formatting. Please [edit] your post and paste the output exactly, then format it as code so we can see the actual characters. I would happily edit it myself, but at the moment I cannot tell whether your files actually contain `>` characters at the start of the lines and double line breaks, or those are your attempt to format the content accurately.

Comment: @Zanna I already assumed the latter and fixed the formatting as I would have expected it...

Comment: john deo... you rolled back Byte Commander's edit, so we still don't know what is actually in your file -_-

Comment: @Zanna I edited the question too to add code blocks. Third time lucky?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
$ sed -r 's|/[^/]*$||' file | sed -r 's|([^/]*/?[^/]*/?[^/]*).*|\1|'
Modified folders: html/project1/old
Modified folders: html/port5
Modified folders: html/trap/dev8
Modified folders: html/bla3/test
Modified folders: html/bla4/pro1
Modified folders: html/bla10/dev
Modified folders: html/bla11/dev
```

Or you can do the second part with `cut`:

```
sed -r 's|/[^/]*$||' file | cut -d '/' -f 1,2,3
```

#### Notes

- `-r` use ERE
- `s|old|new|` replace `old` with `new`
- `[^/]*` any number of characters that are not `/`
- `$` end of line
- `/?` zero or one `/`
- `(pattern)` save `pattern` to reference later with `\1`
- `.*` any number of any characters
- `|` (unquoted) shell pipe - passes output of left hand side command to right hand side command
- `cut -d '/'` use `/` as delimiter
- `-f 1,2,3` print the first three fields

Comment: Doesn't match the 2nd example line, OP wants to strip file names away too...

Comment: My attempt would have been `grep -Po '^.*?(/[^/]*){0,2}(?=/|$)'`, but that suffers the same issue, and I can not figure it out now. Feel free to use it if it helps you.

Comment: @ByteCommander thanks for that. I fixed it, but I don't like piping. I will look for a nicer way

Comment: @zanna thanks a ton. Thanks for simplifying things for me.. i really need to learn shell scripting... Anyway, thanks. Have a great day mate.

Comment: @PerlDuck my knowledge of Perl is sub-beginner level. Please post an answer :)

Comment: @johndeo most welcome :)

Comment: @PerlDuck Thanks for the answer. I really can't understand even a single word of your code.. All I know is.. it's **dope**!!!

Answer (score 3):

The following script will (almost) do as you ask.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>) {
    s!^(Modified\s+folders:\s+)((?:[^/]+/){1,3}).*?$!$1$2!;
    print;
}

__DATA__
Modified folders: html/project1/old/dev/vendor/symfony/yaml/Tests/bla.yml
Modified folders: html/port5/.DS_Store
Modified folders: html/trap/dev8/.DS_Store
Modified folders: html/bla3/test/appl/.DS_Store
Modified folders: html/bla4/pro1/app/bla/Api2.php
Modified folders: html/bla10/dev/appl/language/.DS_Store
Modified folders: html/bla11/dev/appl/language/abc.txt
```

It reads every input line, picks some values from it (my means of a regex), replaces the line with the picked values, and finally prints the now modified line (to STDOUT).

**Output**

```
Modified folders: html/project1/old/
Modified folders: html/port5/
Modified folders: html/trap/dev8/
Modified folders: html/bla3/test/
Modified folders: html/bla4/pro1/
Modified folders: html/bla10/dev/
Modified folders: html/bla11/dev/
```

If we write the regex in one single line:

```
s!^(Modified\s+folders:\s+)((?:[^/]+/){1,3}).*?$!$1$2!;
```

then it looks a bit scary but it is actually quite simple. The basic operator is the [*substitution operator* `s///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) from Perl.

```
s/foo/bar/;
```

will replace every occurence of `foo` with `bar`. `s` allows us to change the delimiter from `/` to something different. I used a `!` here, so we could also write

```
s!foo!bar!;
```

The `!` does *not* mean `not` it's just an arbitrary character here. `sLfooLbarL;` would work as well. We do that because if we use the standard `/` we would need to escape the `/` within the parameters (which is then known as toothpick syntax). Consider we want to replace the path `/old/path` with `/new/path`. Now compare:

```
s/\/old\/path/\/new\/path/; # escaping of / needed
s!/old/path!/new/path!;     # no escaping of / needed (but of ! if we had one in the text)
```

We can also apply the `x` modifier to the `s///`. It allows for arbitrary whitespace (even newlines and comments) in the *pattern* (the left hand side) to improve readablity. Now the loop can be written as:

```
while(<DATA>) {
    s!^                         # match beginning of line
      (Modified\s+folders:\s+)  # the word "Modified", followed by 1 ore more 
                                # whitespace \s+,
                                # the literal "folders:", also followed by 1 or 
                                # more whitespace.
                                # We capture that match in $1 (that's why we have 
                                # parens around it).
      (                         # begin of 2nd capture group (in $2)
        (?:                     #   begin a group that is NOT captured (because of the "?:"
         [^/]+/                 #   one or more characters that are not a slash followed by a slash
        )                       #   end of group
        {1,3}                   #   this group should appear one to three times
      )                         # close capture group $2, i.e. remember the 1-3x slash thing
      .*?$                      # followed by arbitrary characters up to the end of line
     !$1$2!x;                   # Replace the line with the two found captures $1 and $2, i.e.
                                # with the text "Modified folders:" and the 1-3x slash thing.
    print;
}
```

---

The complete "script" can also be written as a one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's!^(Modified\s+folders:\s+)((?:[^/]+/){1,3}).*?$!$1$2!x;' file
```

---

### Update

I just realized that the `Modified folders:` string can be seen as a component of the path as well.
So the pattern can be simplified to

```
perl -pe 's!^((?:[^/]+/){1,3}).*?$!$1!;' file
```

Comment: very cool (+1)!

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -oP '^.*?(/.*?){0,2}(?=/)'
```

a brief explanation of the *dark* regexp used:

- `^...` i the beginning of the line
- `.*?` a seq. of chars (but just the necessary amount) to match the pre-path
- `/.*?){0,2}` 0, 1 or 2 directories
- `(?=/)` look ahead expression -- followed by a `/` that is not included

Comment: Could you expand your answer with details about what this is supposed to do?

Comment: This is way cooler than [the Perl answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/998638/504066) because it also drops the trailing `/`.